# "expression must have (pointer-to) function type" on calloc during 2D array allocation

Tags: c++, oop, multidimensional-array, calloc

In VS2010 `calloc` is highlighted with the error "expression must have (pointer-to) function type" in the following code block *only when it is inside of a member-function of a class*.  When it is placed in the `main()`, there is no problem.  There are no variables named calloc.

```
RoadSegment ***map;

map = (RoadSegment ***) calloc(nRows, sizeof(RoadSegment **));
for( int rCur=0; rCur < nRows; ++rCur )
    map[rCur] = (RoadSegment **) calloc(nCols, sizeof(RoadSegment *));
```

I don't understand what the difference could be, nonetheless why the error is occurring in the first place in the member-function.

Comment: Sorry, I have an unrelated question, but when you call `calloc` with the `sizeof(RoadSegment **)`... does that mean you are allocating space for pointers?

Comment: My guess would be a #define something that is defining `calloc` in a way that is not compatible inside that particular class method. Any reason why you are using `calloc()` in the first place instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: only #define I made is for NULL.  Using calloc for practice

Comment: I was using `"stdlib.h"`, switched to the standard as you suggested, using `<cstdlib>` and `std::calloc`.  VS2010 just highlights all the `std`s with the same error...

Comment: @BWG Yes, making a 2D array of pointers overall

Comment: Is your member function defined in a header?  If so, is `<cstdlib>` included before that header is included, or as part of the header?

Comment: @paddy Your last question led to the fix.  `<cstdlib>` needs to be above the class header include.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @vlad417 Okay, glad to help.  Have provided this as an answer, with a bit of extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As predicted by my comment, it turned out that you had not included your headers in the right order.  Your implementation was in a header, and so `<cstdlib>` needed to be included before that header:

```
#include <cstdlib>      // Required by myclass.h
#include "myclass.h"
```

This makes things difficult when you have lots of source files requiring your header - each source file must remember to include other headers, even though they don't need those headers directly.

Here are some different strategies for avoiding this kind of problem:

- Make a habit of always including standard headers and other library headers (anything in angle-brackets) *before* any local headers (anything in double-quotes) - note that each source file still must remember to include the prerequisite headers; or
- If your header uses something from another header, make sure you include the required headers inside your own header (sometimes you have mutually-dependent headers and can't do this - instead you can forward-declare stuff for one of those headers); or
- Use a pre-compiled header that is required for *all* source files and put all the common headers in there (this is the lazy approach, yet common for Microsoft compilers: *ie* `"stdafx.h"` - it has practical uses when you have very large headers that are used everywhere and you want to reduce compile time).

If you are implementing code in a header, make sure it's for the right reasons.  If it's just that you're lazy and don't feel like splitting it into a source file, that's a bad reason.  If it's template code that must be defined in a header, that's a good reason.

Comment: I recommend the second bullet point, along with the coding standard: "Every header should work if included on the first (or only) line of a source file."

Comment: Yep, I agree with you @aschepler - a header is there to provide an interface without you needing to know the implementation details.  So you should be able to just include the header.